# rangy: detach() needs to be called?

Tags: javascript, rangy

I'm using the [rangy library](http://code.google.com/p/rangy/) and reading the docs for `detach`: "Destroys the range when it is no longer to be used.".

Currently there's no good place for me to call `detach` in my code for some ranges I create with `cloneRange`. Since it's an editor I'm working on this code can be called loads of times.

Should I be worried about memory consumption since I'm not calling `detach` or will garbage collection finally collect the non-referenced ranges?

Basically this boils down to the question: will Rangy keep references to created ranges with `cloneRange` preventing garbage collection to work properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are really two `detach` methods: the one on native ranges (those ranges created by `document.createRange()`), and the method that Rangy exposes on its range objects.

#### DOM's `detach`

The reason for `detach` being there at all is that it is mandated by the [DOM Level 2](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Traversal-Range/ranges.html#Level2-Range-method-detach).

Now, going by the discussion in this [bug report](https://www.w3.org/Bugs/Public/show_bug.cgi?id=14591), the idea of `detach` was that it should enable the browser to free up computational resources. As long as a range is in use, the browser has to track it. Judging by the discussion in the bug report, the following appear to be true:

1. Few applications call `Range.detach`.
2. In Firefox, it is a noop.

Moreover, the [WHATWG](http://wiki.whatwg.org/wiki/FAQ#What_is_the_WHATWG.3F) makes it a [noop](http://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#dom-range-detach) so it is likely that browsers will follow suit sooner or later.

#### Rangy's `detach`

The `detach` method that Rangy puts on its ranges calls the DOM's method and performs some internal bookkeeping.

Looking at Rangy's code, I see nothing there that would suggest that calling `detach` on a range created by Rangy would prevent garbage collection problems.

I was wondering what Tim Down (author of Rangy) thought about it, and I found a post by him  [here](https://www.w3.org/Bugs/Public/show_bug.cgi?id=14591#c13). He seems to be on board with getting rid of `detach()`. Probably it will take a while before Rangy removes it if only to be backward compatible.

So I would not bother calling it.

Comment: I agree with all of this. I'm intending to deprecate (but not remove, yet) it in Rangy once I get round to working on it again. I almost left it out in the first version of Rangy but at the time hadn't ruled out the idea of having each Rangy range observe the DOM and update itself when the DOM changes, which would have prevented it being garbage collected as normal when all external references to it disappeared. In that scenario a detach method would have been useful, since there's no way in JavaScript to detect how many references to an object exist. As it is, it's useless.